# Is cpphs wrong or is the behavior of macros with arguments in if defined expressions undefined?

Tags: gcc, macros, c-preprocessor, undefined-behavior

I have the following code that uses a macro with arguments in an **if defined** preprocessor expression:

**preprocessor-games.c**:

```
#define EXAMPLE_MACRO(arg1,arg2) (\
                               arg1 > arg2)

#if defined(EXAMPLE_MACRO)
#endif
```

I preprocess it with GCC and it works without errors:

```
$ gcc -E -undef -traditional -x assembler-with-cpp preprocessor-games.c -o preprocessed-games.c
$ echo $?
0
$
```

And it results in acceptable output:

```
# 1 "preprocessor-games.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4

# 17 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 3 4










































# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "preprocessor-games.c"
```

I preprocess it with alternative preprocessor - [cpphs](http://projects.haskell.org/cpphs/) (intended as close enough emulation of GCC's preprocesor to work for Haskell) - and I get an empty output file and an error message:

```
$ cpphs --cpp -E -undef -traditional -x assembler-with-cpp preprocessor-games.c -o preprocessed-games.c
cpphs: macro EXAMPLE_MACRO expected 2 arguments, but was given 0
$ echo $?
1
$
```

Is cpphs wrong or is the behavior of [macros with arguments](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macro-Arguments.html) in [if defined expressions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Defined.html#Defined) undefined?

Comment: @Mat good point. That's an incorrect statement. It's meant to be close enough to GCC's preprocessor to work for Haskell.  The problem here is that GHC's (a Haskell Compiler) source uses if defined in this way and cpphs doesn't support it.  I'll correct the question.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior is defined. In C99 6.10.3/7 *Macro replacement*:

> The identifier immediately following the `define` is called the **macro name**.

(Following paragraphs go on and define *object-like macros* and *function-like macros*. But *macro name* is generic.)

And back in 6.10.1 *Conditional inclusion*:

> The expression that controls conditional [...] and it may contain unary operator expressions of the form
>
> ```
> defined identifier
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> defined ( identifier )
> ```
>
> which evaluate to 1 if the identifier is currently defined as a macro name (that is, if it is predefined or if it has been the subject of a `#define` preprocessing directive without an intervening `#undef` directive with the same subject identifier), 0 if it is not.

There is no difference made between object-like or function-like macros: `defined` checks for a defined *macro name*, and that applies to both.

Comment: Great.  Thank you @Mat.  That is exactly what I need.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question. Seems to me the question is about why `cpphs` behaves differently for `#if defined(MACRO)`.  It seems to want to expand `MACRO` in this construct, when it should really be just checking if it is defined. Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: @Ziffusion: the question is whether cpphs is wrong or whether that use of `define` is not standard in the first place (as I understand it). I argue that the construct is well defined, which implies that cpphs is wrong to bork on it.